# Android AnimatorSet.cancel() does not work on Marshmallow version devices

Tags: android, animation, animatorset

```
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
ValueAnimator anim1 = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
ValueAnimator anim2 = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f, 0f);
~~~
animatorSet.play(anim1).after(anim2);
animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        Log.d("Testing", "cancel");
    }
}

animatorSet.start();


button.setOnclickListener((v) -> {
    animatorSet.cancel();
})
```

When the `Button` is clicked, the cancel listener works well. However, `cancel()` is not called only in `API23` version (`Marshmallow`).
What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your `cancel()` method to this:

```
public void cancel() {
  if (animatorSet != null) {
    animatorSet.cancel();
  }
  if (next != null) {
    next.cancel();
    next = null;
  }
}
```

It should work for API 23 also. If not, please share more code of your project to rebuild it and find another solution.

Comment: Does Animatorset have a clearAnimation function? I think it only have cancel and end function.